# Etag support for landing/index page. Subsequent requests does not include the previous etag from the browser

Tags: javascript, web, browser, etag

Trying to figure out how we could possibly make use of etags mainly for the index/source page.

However, when writing the Etag in the response 123, subsequent requests does not include it from the browser to determine the response.

Any idea? Is this not possible for the landing page? Perhaps only intended for data requests?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Revalidation (i.e the use of `ETags`) only happens when a resource expires from the cache. But you've set an expiration date 15 years into the future, so there won't be an opportunity for revalidation. (And caching for that long is not a good idea for a landing page. See [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/) for a reasonable caching strategy.)

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Yes, i discovered i need to set cache to zero basically. However, I have hit another issue. When redirecting (language change) to the landing page, it appears the etag if-not-modified is not revalidated despite various headers. I can not get chrome to revalidate on redirect from the server. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722857/how-to-correctly-prevent-caching-of-302-redirect-location